# getElementById returning null for Canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, web, null

When I run the code below I get 'null' for the variable surface. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<html>

<body>
    <script>
        var surface = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        console.log("surface: " + surface);
    </script>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150">
        <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
    </canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element doesn't exist yet when you're trying to get it, move the script tag so the element comes before it in the DOM

```
<html>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150">
        <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
    </canvas>

    <script>
        var surface = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        console.log("surface: " + surface);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is essentially why most scripts start with $(document).ready

Comment: @MikeBell - If you're using jQuery maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Place your javascript after the canvas, its quite possibly running before the canvas is rendered on the page.